# Swift generic extension for an array in array

Tags: swift, generics, swift-extensions

I want to define a extension to Array (or Sequence or Collector?) so I can query a list of lists of a custom object with a NSIndexPath and get the object based on the indexPath's section and row.

```
public var tableViewData = [[MyCellData]]() // Populated elsewhere

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var tableViewCellData = tableViewData.data(from: indexPath)
    // use tableViewCellData
}

// This does not compile as I want the return type to be that of which is the type "in the list in the list" (i.e. MyCellData)
extension Sequence<T> where Iterator.Element:Sequence, Iterator.Element.Element:T {
    func object(from indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> T {
        return self[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- A `Sequence` cannot be indexed via subscript, so you need a 
  `Collection`.
- The collections elements must be collections as well.
- Since `.row`, `.section` are `Int`, the collection 
  and its nested collection must be indexed by `Int`.
  (This is the case for many collections, e.g. arrays or array slices.
  `String.CharacterView` is an example of a collection which is *not*
  indexed by `Int`.)
- You don't need any generic placeholder (and `extension Sequence<T>`
  is not valid Swift 3 syntax). Just specify the return type as the
  element type of the nested collection.

Putting it all together:

```
extension Collection where Index == Int, Iterator.Element: Collection, Iterator.Element.Index == Int {
    func object(from indexPath: IndexPath) -> Iterator.Element.Iterator.Element {
        return self[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!